# Procedural code from function to OOP

Tags: php, function, oop

I would like to learn OOP but I have a problem how to convert procedural code to OOP. How can I covert procedural code from **function oblicz()** to OOP standard? Do I have to make a new classes for example for **$wynik_skryptu** and **$url**? How to connect it to one function oblicz() ? Now it takes so long that script calculate me values. Is it worth to convert it to OOP style?

```
class Dystans {

    public $obliczony;
    public $szergeo1;
    public $dluggeo1;
    public $szergeo2;
    public $dluggeo2;


      function __construct($s1, $d1, $s2, $d2)
      {
          $this->szergeo1 = $s1;
          $this->dluggeo1 = $d1;
          $this->szergeo2 = $s2;
          $this->dluggeo2 = $d2;          
      }


public function oblicz (){

$wynik_skryptu = array();
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={$this->szergeo1},{$this->dluggeo1}&destinations={$this->szergeo2},{$this->dluggeo2}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false&key=***************";

$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$wynik_skryptu = json_decode($data, true);

$this->obliczony = $wynik_skryptu['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
return ($this->obliczony)/1000;

}

}
```

Comment: Is there something inside `oblicz()` that you could use in another method/class?

Comment: I would like only use this value in the other part of PHP script: ($this->obliczony)/1000